# Pass url variable on to next page?

Tags: php, session, variables

I need some help on passing a url php variable onto the next page.  I've tried searching throughout the site for help and I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out with no luck. Basically I need to be able to change the paypal link button id on page 2 with the url variable from page 1.

**The variable is initially passed along with the URL: `http://www.example.com?p=paypalbuttonid`
I would like to store and pass that "p" variable on to the next page. I don't want to pass the variable onto page 2 with a link. I would prefer to store the variable and recall it on page 2.**

**Page 1 code (above html):**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['paypal'] = $_GET['p'];
?>
```

**Page 2 code (above html):**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $p = $_SESSION['paypal'];
?>
```

**I'm calling the variable in a link on page 2 (body):**

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=<?php echo $p ;?>" target="_blank" class="btn">
```

I'm not sure what I'm dong wrong but I'm a complete newbie to PHP so please help! The variable shows up blank in the URL on page 2. Thank you!  - Chad

Comment: I need the paypal id to change according to the id in the url. Other people will need to change the paypal id to their own.

Comment: I replicated your code, and htis works fine for me.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Make sure the session options is set correctly.

Comment: What happens when you print out $_SESSION with `print_r($_SESSION);`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure you dont have any output before session_start(), it is safe to put session_start () at the top of the page , especially if you use php code in .html, since you may have output without awareness, and session wont work if you have anything output to the browser before session_start()

according to php.net:

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

and you should check if you cookie is enabled.

Secondly, `var_dump ($_SESSION);` to see if you can get anything

Comment: in addition to that, you should use isset ($_GET['p']) to test so that it wont generate any E-warning

Comment: add more to the second part please. For somebody learning, they may not follow why you should do that, or where.